# What configuration required to create a special user in OpenLdap for redmine server to authenticate other users

Tags: redmine, openldap

First of all i am new to OpenLDAP. I have installed OpenLDAP server and Redmine in GCE (google compute engine).
I am unable to decide how to create a special user in OpenLDAP so that redmine can use the user account to authenticate users when logged into Redmine.
Here is the OpenLDAP structure image link:

[image: Screenshot of existing LDAP structure]

Please help me create/modify the user for Redmine LDAP authentication.

Comment: Thanks Holger for editing the question and adding screenshot as i don't have rights to put images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not the one initially who configured our LDAP auth for redmine, and I'm not well-versed in LDAP terminology, but I compared our settings to yours.

You might try the following settings in Redmine:

```
Account: cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=trickytechnos,dc=in
Password: the LDAP admin's password
Base DN: ou=people,dc=ldap,dc=trickytechnos,dc=in
```

If that works, then you might want to go back and create a similar LDAP user (other than admin) so that you can give it more limited permissions.

Comment: Hi @joecullin, I have tried what u suggested and it worked. i have created a new new user, but little confused as how to make that user read only user. Here is the LDIF file content.  # Entry 1: cn=redmine,dc=ldap,dc=trickytechnos,dc=in
dn: cn=redmine,dc=ldap,dc=trickytechnos,dc=in
cn: redmine
description: redmine administrator
objectclass: simpleSecurityObject
objectclass: organizationalRole
objectclass: top
userpassword: {SSHA}somehashpassword